# Impact of IELTS score on PhD Application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, international-students, language-exams

I received an overall score of 7.5 on the IELTS exam, but unfortunately, I only scored a 6 in the writing section. The Ph.D. programs I am applying to require an overall score of 6.5 or 7, but they did not specify any minimum requirements for individual modules. Will my lower score in writing affect my application?

Comment: I would say it depends on the country you are applying to, the university, the fields, if the application is directed towards the whole department, or a specific professor, etc. A lot of factor that may impact the decision, without taking into account the most important: it all depends on the people processing the application. If you are really worried, send an email, but whether they do need a minimum requirements for individual modules or not, you can't change your score anymore

Comment: I am applying to biomedical sciences program in the USA.

Comment: Your English here is perfectly acceptable, so the English in your application probably is too. If I saw an application with good writing I would probably pay no attention to the exam score.

Comment: @EthanBolker Not at all saying it regarding to Maliha English, but with tools such as chatGPT now, people processing application may ignore/pay less attention the quality in the application and pay more attention to scores.

Comment: @JackRed I'm glad I retired before I had to confront that problem.

Comment: @JackRed That's what I am afraid too. They would not understand if I wrote the application components on my own or used chatGPT.

Comment: @MalihaKabir I think it's fine. I was raising the counterpoint that the application could have been made with assistance and thus may not be a proof. It may not end up helping, but it won't be a negative thing. The main point is still your score, and the threshold they have for it, overall or per section, which you should seek the answer yourself if you really want to, as suggested by buffy in her answer. It won't change anything in the end however as you already have your test

Answer (score 2):

They have stated a standard and you seem to have met it. If you have stated the case correctly then you should be fine.

If you still have doubts, the best answer will come from the institution itself, perhaps a "graduate office" rather than from an admissions committee or individual professor. Perhaps the department administration.